Google login doesn't redirect
I having trouble with my google login using firebase auth. What i want to do is if the user email is already exist in the database it will redirect the user to its respective page and then if not, the user will be redirected to sign up form with the google user info from google pre-filled in the form(it's working). The only problem is that if I try to login with the email that's already in the database it doesn't redirects me to home page.
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    const user = result.user;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", `check.php?email=${encodeURIComponent(user.email)}`, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          try {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("Response:", response); // Log the response for debugging

            if (response.exists) {
              switch (response.role) {
                case "job_seeker":
                  window.location.href = "job_seeker_home.php";

                  break;

                case "employer":
                  window.location.href = "employer_home.php";

                  break;

                default:
                  console.error("Unknown role:", response.role);

                // Handle unknown roles here
              }
            } else {
              window.location.href = `login.php?form_type=signup&name=${encodeURIComponent(
                user.displayName
              )}&email=${encodeURIComponent(user.email)}`;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing response:", error);
          }
        } else {
          console.error("Request failed with status:", xhr.status);
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
      console.error("Request failed");
    };

    xhr.send();
  })

  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error during sign-in:", error);
  });




Using xhr.open("GET", check.php?email=${encodeURIComponent(user.email)}, true); is not a good thing you do.  Rather use this:
xhr.open("POST", "check.php", true);       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");       xhr.send("email="+user.email);
